# Django - HTTP ERROR 405 - Method Not Allowed (GET): /account/logout

Tags: python-3.x, django

When try to click logout button, shows this http://127.0.0.1:8000/account/logout

In terminal shows,
[11/Feb/2024 07:03:26] "GET /account/logout HTTP/1.1" 405 0
Method Not Allowed (GET): /account/logout
Method Not Allowed: /account/logout

```
In urls.py

from django.urls import path
from users_app import views
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns = [
    path('register', views.register, name='register'),
    path('login', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='login.html'), name='login'),
    path('logout', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='logout.html'), name='logout')

]
```

```
In logout.html

{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block title %}
    <title>Logged Out - Taskmate</title>
{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="container"> 
    </br>
        <h4>Logged Out Of TaskMate, Thank You For Using Us!</h4>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

When clicked on to Logout button, expected to appear the text as "Logged Out Of TaskMate, Thank You For Using Us!"